# Update con múltiples tablas relacionadas php

Tags: php, join

Tengo un formulario que me permite actualizar un producto con el cual utilizo un `query` para actualizar 4 tablas que se relacionan. Pero no logro que este se ejecute de manera satisfactoria. Para brindar mas información las 4 tablas son: `precios, letras, planes y proveedor` y se relacionan de la siguiente manera: `precios con letras`, `letras con planes` y `planes con proveedor`; el producto queda cargado con los siguientes datos: *`nombre(tabla plan)`*, *`valor asegurado(tabla precios)`*, *`prima anual(tabla precios)`*, *`opción A (tabla letras)`*, *`proveedor(proveedor)`*. Como pueden observar todas estas van de la mano y este es el query que tengo.

```
 UPDATE planes INNER JOIN proveedor ON planes.proveedor = proveedor.codproveedor INNER JOIN letras ON letras.planes_id = planes.idplanes INNER JOIN precios ON 
                          precios.letras_opciones = letras.letras_id
                          SET proveedor = '$proveedor', nombre = '$nombre',
                          prima_anual = '$prima_anual', valor_asegurado = '$valor_asegurado'
               WHERE planes.idplanes = $idplanes
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer un update por tabla. Puedes poner todas las queries dentro de una misma transaccion, de manera que si falla una fallen todas.

Comment: Tienes que especificar los nombre de tabla (¿y alias?) en `UPDATE`, así como en cada columna a actualizar. Revisa [este artículo](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/).

Comment: @Triby el nombre de las tablas las especifico en el enunciado , no tienen alias pero te las dejo por aquí: precios,letras,planes,proveedor

Comment: @nachospiu no se como haría podrías regalarme un ejemplo de ello?

Comment: Si. Que base de datos estas usando? Que librería usas  para acceder a la base de datos?  Subí la estructura de las 4 tablas (el create table), para verlo más claro. Necesito esa información para poder hacer un ejemplo adecuado.

Comment: Añadí también el fragmento de código de php, asi veo con que datos contas.

Comment: Hace un rato preguntaron exactamente lo mismo, y vuelvo a decir lo mismo. Probaste que esa query ande en tu base de datos? tira algun error? los datos de entrada estan bien? si es mysql, SI se puede hacer un update con join (aunque es una barbaridad)... php aca no tiene nada que ver, salvo que el problema sea que no vengan datos....

Comment: @codek, supongo que no leíste el artículo, donde se ve este ejemplo: `UPDATE T1,T2 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 SET T1.C2 = T2.C2, T2.C3 = expr WHERE condition`, especificando nombre de todas las tablas involucradas en `UPDATE` y como prefijo para cada columna a actualizar. Desconozco si existen problemas de rendimiento, seguridad u otro, pero parece que sí se puede hacer.

Comment: Logre hacer el Update pero al momento de modificar el precio de una opción, ya sea a, b o c que las cargo mediante un select dinámico, si selecciono la a y pongo el precio me actualiza el mismo precio en las demás opciones y la idea es que si selecciono el precio de la A solo me cambie ese precio y no el de las otras. @Triby